# Послать клик по кнопке другой программе

Tags: delphi

Имею две программы, просто формы с кнопками. Одна программа по кнопке вызывает exe файл другой программы и делает её дочерним окном. Не получается послать нажатие кнопки(что лежит на форме второй программы) после открытия.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var hw:hwnd;
FormRgn:HRGN;
wnd:THandle;
begin

ShellExecute(Handle, 'open','D:\12\12 \Win32\Debug\Web.exe',nil,nil,SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE);
 sleep(100);
hw:=FindWindow(nil,'Web'); //находим хендел нужного окна
Windows.SetParent(hw,Handle); //делаем его дочерним окном приложения
MoveWindow(hw,0,0,ClientWidth,ClientHeight,true); //смещаем окно в позицию 0 0

FormRgn:=CreateRectRgn(7,30,Width-200,Height-100); //указываем какую область оставим видимой
SetWindowRgn(hw, FormRgn, TRUE); //обрезаем все лишнее

wnd:=FindWindow(nil,'Web'); // ищем окно по названию
wnd:=FindWindowEx(wnd,0,nil,'Web'); // ищем кнопку по названию
wnd:=FindWindowEx(wnd,0,nil,'start'); // ищем кнопку по названию
SendMessage(wnd,WM_LBUTTONDOWN,0,0); // жмем кнопку
SendMEssage(wnd,WM_LBUTTONUP,0,0); //отпускаем кнопку
end;
```

Comment: вашему коду не достает кучи проверок - нашлось что-нибудь по ***каждому*** вызову FindWindow или нет?

Comment: "Одна программа по кнопке вызывает exe файл другой программы и делает её дочерним окном." Я, конечно, могу ошибаться, но что-то я сильно сомневаюсь, что можно сделать дочерним окном окно другого процесса (приложения).

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, спасибо что отозвались. 
 Было ведь логично ,что после того как окно стало дочерним, нужно было использовать хендл основной программы.